# How do I represent the following equations

Tags: equations

I am having trouble drawing the right hand side. Any ideas? 
[image]

Comment: To align the equations you could use `\begin{align*}`. For the `=` with text you can use `\overset`.

Comment: @manooooh How do I add the braces in equation2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\eqdef}{\mathrel{\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}}}
%\renewcommand{\eqdef}{\mathrel{\overset{\mathclap{\mathrm{def}}}{=}}}
\newcommand{\prob}{\mathrm{P}\probnotation}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\probnotation}{(}{)}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \phi_1 &\eqdef \bigwedge_{i = 1}^k \prob[\big]{ f_{s_i}(e), f_{t_i}(e) } \\
  \phi_2 &\eqdef \forall v \forall w \biggl( \prob{v, w} \rightarrow
    \bigwedge_{i = 1}^k \prob[\big]{ f_{s_i}(v), f_{t_i}(w) } \biggr) \\
  \phi_3 &\eqdef \exists z \, \prob{z, z}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Two options for `\eqdef` is presented. The second uses `\mathclap` to remove any overlap spacing inserted by the `def` `\overset`. It depends on your preference, and possibly if `\eqdef` is used in the same `align` with `=`.

You may also consider a smaller rendering of `def` via

```
\newcommand{\eqdef}{\mathrel{\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{def}}{=}}}
```